# Toasting bagel in my oven

Tags: oven, toasting, toaster

How much energy am I wasting by toasting my bagel in my big oven? Should I get a toaster?

Comment: Are these frozen bagels, or (reasonably) fresh?  If fresh and/or day old, you can heat up a cast iron pan, and then set the cut side down on it, and wait a minute or so.  It also has the advantage that it doesn't heat the outside so much that you can't hold it.

Comment: They arn't fozen, but they are refrigerated. Neat idea, but I don't like the insides of my bagels toasted, just the outsides.

Comment: Are you using a broiler in the oven, or are you preheating the whole oven just for toasting?  Putting a bagel under a broiler for a quick toast will probably waste more energy than a toaster, but it's still just heating one element for a relatively short time. If you're heating a big oven several hundred degrees just to toast a bagel, obviously that's going to waste a lot more energy.

Comment: I am preheating the entire oven. I don't know what broiling is. I vaguely remember seeing it on my oven, I'll take a look when i go home.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A toaster is more efficient than a toaster oven, which in turn is far more efficient than heating an entire conventional oven.

Toaster statistics:
Approximate time to make toast – 4 minutes
Watt measured while running – 820 W
Resulting electricity usage – 0.055 kWh

vs

Toaster oven statistics:
Approximate time to make toast – 5 minutes
Watt measured while running – 1110 W
Resulting kWh usage – 0.093

Lower kWh usage means the toaster is more efficient than a toaster oven.

[Here](https://itisscience.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/toaster-v-toaster-oven/) is the source for the comparison of toaster vs toaster oven.

Now, you can compare the less efficient toaster oven to a conventional oven [here](http://blog.constellation.com/2016/05/20/toaster-oven-vs-microwave-energy-efficiency/) (or to a microwave, but you don't really use that for toast). Toaster ovens use about 1/3 to 1/2 the energy of a conventional oven. So if a toaster uses less than a toaster oven, and a toaster oven uses far less than an oven, then clearly a toaster would be far less wasteful than the oven.

So YES, buy a toaster!